# Integrating JBOSS and Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, jboss

I have JBOSS server. I used to make web applications using just notepad++. I used to create the necessary folders like web-inf and files like web.xml. For larger projects doing all this and manually compiling has become cumbersome. I want to use eclipse for that. I saw this tutorial - http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/community/tutorials/BuildJ2EEWebApp/BuildJ2EEWebApp.html . But I don't understand how to make a server. I already have a server.
 **What I want to do is write JSPs and Servlets in eclipse and the build should automatically be deployed in jboss server.**
 How to to this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Install [**JBoss Tools**](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/node/420896)

After that follow the instructions from [**here**](https://docs.jboss.org/jbossweb/3.0.x/deployer-howto.html) to get started and deploy apps to JBoss Server.

To automatically deploy apps after the build you could use a build tool such as ANT or Maven.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a tutorial for this some time ago: [Setting up web development environments with Eclipse](http://www.software-architect.net/tutorials/setting-up-a-web-development-environment-with-eclipse/setting-up-the-application-server-jboss.html)

It shows how to setup JBoss within Eclipse (in addition, it also shows how to setup Tomcat and Weblogic), and also shows how to build a simple sample Servlet to verify the proper installation.

Answer (score 1):

If you already use JBoss on the server side, then have a look at the client side as well: http://www.jboss.org/developer

(I haven't tried it myself, but...)

Answer (score 1):

Just open eclipse then go to:

1. "Help-> Check For Updates" It will check for eclipse updates and installs new availables.
2. Now "Help -> Eclipse Market Place" Search for "Jboss tools" from search result select   one(as your eclipse version) and install it. It will add adapter for new jboss versions.
3. Now add new server from server view select Jboss version then next add your Home directory of jboss. Then finish.

Step 1 is optional but it sometime it helps.